# Redirecting moved blog content using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have moved a blog that was previously stored at `http://www.example.com/ourblog/` to the root of the domain (`http://www.example.com/`). Everything is up and running perfectly, but I need all the previous Google listing to point to the new content.

So, for example:
`http://www.example.com/ourblog/category/comedy/` should redirect to
`http://www.example.com/category/comedy/`

And:
`http://www.example.com/ourblog/my-post/` should redirect to
`http://www.example.com/my-post/`

etc.

It's a Wordpress blog, but I haven't been able to find anything in the Wordpress documentation that offers a solution.

I've tried adding a simple rule to .htaccess:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/$ http://www.example.com/
```

and

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/.*$ http://www.example.com/
```

But while it redirects `http://www.example.com/blog/` to `http://www.example.com/` it doesn't handle any of the sub directories.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the more powerful mod_rewrite. This should get exactly what you need and handle any sub directories.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ourblog/(.*)/?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect it using RedirectMatch directive,

Try this

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/Ourblog/(.*)/?$ http://www.example.com/$1
```